# How can I rearrange all midi instruments sequentially instead of simultaneously?

Tags: python, midi

I have a large list of midi files. Each midi file has several tracks for every instrument. I want to take each track, for instance: violin, piano, etc. and instead of having them play concurrently, rearrange them so they play one after the other in one combined midi file.

In other words, I want to combine them in series as opposed to in parallel on python.

I've tried this following code, but this actually combines things in parallel, not in series:

```
import midi
import os

path = input("Input folder name:")

pattern = midi.Pattern()
with os.scandir(path) as it:
    for entry in it:
        if entry.name.endswith(".mid") and entry.is_file():
            print(entry.name)
            try:
                midifile = midi.read_midifile(entry.path)
            except TypeError:
                continue
            for track in midifile:
                pattern.append(track)

            #print(entry.name, entry.path)

midi.write_midifile('combined.mid', pattern)
```

As I'm not familiar with dealing with midi libraries, I'd love any help whatsoever on how to go about doing this.

Comment: You have to shift the messages in each track by the duration of the previous tracks. Which library are you using?

Comment: I'm using python3-midi but really am not attached to a library at the moment so I welcome any recommendations for a good library that can do this

Comment: As I said, you have to change the messages' ticks. What exactly is the problem with that?

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the help.